# How do I see source or javadocs for a library dependency in an Android package in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

I have two packages^ in Eclipse. One is marked as a Library and the other references it (under properties->Android), as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

My problem is that when I hover the mouse over some code referring to the referenced project eclipse displays

> "This element has no attached javadoc and the javadoc could not be found in the attached source"

Furthermore when I select "Open Declaration" in the context menu for said code, it opens the associated .class (instead of the .Java) with the messsage

> "The JAR of this class file belongs to container 'Android Dependencies' which does not allow  modifications to source attachments on entries"

^ root nodes in the Package Explorer, so I assume they're called packages and not projects. Neither of them are jars.

Answer (score 10):

this should have been fixed in latest adt version, but in case someone still have this problem like me, here's what i did:

I switched the order of src in .classpath file of my library projects, to this (note that the path="src" must be in the first line)

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfect. So easy and yet totally non-intuitive.

Answer (score -1):

If you right click on a jar file, you can go to the properties menu. In that there is javadoc location option on the side which allows u to specify the path. Might work for the library project too.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a jar file. It's a package. ("I have two packages^")

Comment: Tried it on both the library and referrer with no result either.