# How can I attach source to an Android eclipse project dependencies?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have two `Android` eclipse projects, one that contains my application and one set as library that contains common code. The application project uses the common project as a dependency, when I attempt to debug the code in the common project by stepping through the application project I get this error:

`The JAR of this class file belongs to container 'Android Dependencies' which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries`

I am already aware of **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873152/how-to-attach-javadoc-or-sources-to-jars-in-libs-folder)** answer which covers attaching sources to JARs, but it does not mention anywhere how to do the same for eclipse project dependencies.

How can I attach source to an Android eclipse project dependencies?

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17520652/513038.  Don't forget to clean and build.